# Jest withTypeScript syntaxerror unexpected token, expected ";"

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I've been trying to setup jest for use with typescript and I've tried a bunch of fixes with no luck. I'm getting the error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected ";"`, I think the config isn't supporting typescript code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGBCa.png

If anybody has any suggestions I'd be very grateful!

Here's my package.json:

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "ts-jest",
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.js",
      "**/*.ts",
      "!__tests__/util.ts",
      "!coverage/**",
      "!**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.tsx?$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "verbose": true,
    "automock": false,
    "clearMocks": true,
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "jest-extended"
    ],
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/"
    ],
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ]
  }
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "target": "esnext",
    "types": ["@emotion/core", "@types/jest", "jest"],
    "rootDir": ".",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the `transform` configuration, you are asking jest to use `babel-jest` for `tsx` files when I would say it should be `ts-jest`.

You can even remove the `transform` configuration since the `ts-jest` preset handles `ts` and `tsx` by default.

Comment: hm yea that did fix the problem, but now I'm getting the "jest encountered an unexpected token" for the import of that file. I think this one is more documented. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use `esbuild-jest`

```json
  transform: {
    '\\.[jt]sx?$': 'esbuild-jest',
  },
```